# Find $\Lambda$ such that it reaches its norm at $x_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be $c_0$ the space of sequences such that they converge to $0$, with the supremum norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{\infty}$. Let $x_0=(1,1,0,\dots)\in X$. I want to find all the elements of the dual space $\Lambda\in X^*$ such that $\lVert \Lambda \rVert=1$ and $\Lambda$ reaches its norm at $x_0$, i.e., $|\Lambda(x_0)|=\lVert \Lambda \rVert\lVert x_0 \rVert_{\infty}$.

So, here's my attempt. We know that $X^*=\ell_1$, since there exists the isometric homeomorphism $\Phi:\ell_1\rightarrow X^*$, given by $\Phi(y)=\Lambda_y$, where $\Lambda_y:X^*\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $\Lambda_y(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_ny_n$. This $\Phi$ verifies that $\lVert \Lambda_y\rVert = \lVert y \rVert_1$.

This said, we want $\Lambda_y$ to have norm $1$, so $1=\lVert \Lambda_y\rVert = \lVert y \rVert_1$. Then, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|y_n|=1.$

Now, since $\Lambda_y\in X^*$, we know that $\lVert \Lambda_y(x)\rVert \leq \lVert \Lambda_y \rVert\lVert x\rVert_{\infty},\,\forall x\in X$. But $\Lambda_y$ reaches its norm at $x_0$, so $\lVert \Lambda_y(x_0)\rVert = \lVert \Lambda_y \rVert\lVert x_0\rVert_{\infty} = 1$. Then, $|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\xi_ny_n|=|y_1+y_2|=1$, because $x_0=(\xi_n)_{n\geq1}$ verifies $\xi_n=0, n\ge3$.

With this, $1=|y_1+y_2|\le|y_1|+|y_2|$. So, $1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|y_n|\ge 1+ \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}|y_n|$. Finally, we conclude that $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}|y_n|=0$, so $y_n=0,n\ge 3$.

Now, I have that $|y_1+y_2|=1$ and $|y_1|+|y_2|=1$, so $|y_1+y_2|=|y_1|+|y_2|$. Since the triangular inequality is an equality, we have two cases: $y_1,y_2\ge 0$ or $y_1,y_2\le0$

If $y_1,y_2\ge 0$, we have that $y_1+y_2=1 \implies y_1=1-y_2$. Since both are non-negative numbers we conclude that $y_1,y_2\in[0,1]$. Then, renaming $y_1=\lambda$, we conclude that $\Lambda_y(x)=\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2, \lambda\in[0,1]$.

If $y_1,y_2\le 0$, we have that $-y_1-y_2=1 \implies y_1=-y_2-1$. As in the previous case, we conclude that $y_1,y_2\in[-1,0]$. So, again, renaming $y_1=\lambda$, we have that $\Lambda_y(x)=\lambda x_1-(1+\lambda)x_2$.

With this, we would have finished. Is this approach correct? I don't know why, but the the second case bothers me a little bit. Is there, maybe, a better or clever way of solving this?

Thank you very much!